# Как связывать игроков между собой в парной онлайн игре?

Tags: android, алгоритм, разработка-игр, сеть

Появилась идея создать морской бой онлайн для Android. Игра уже готова, но вот проблема: я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы двух игроков загоняло в одну комнату при поиске игры. Т.е. в главном меню есть кнопка поиск игры, нажимаешь и ждешь пока найдется другой игрок, как найдется - оба игрока загоняются в одну комнату и играют в морской бой.

Если решения для вас очевидно, пожалуйста, поделитесь, потому как я не знаю как это реализовать. Хотя бы кратко по шагам, что за чем делать.

Comment: А у игры вообще есть какая-то серверная часть? Если есть, то не очень понятно, в чём проблема.

Comment: Пока нет сервера. Есть только игра на Android, морской бой против бота. Хочу ее переделать в онлайн. Поэтому и спрашиваю, потому как не знаю, с  чего начать и как реализовывать.

Comment: поднимать сервер, разработать протокол передачи ходов с/на сервер. Бот переместить на сервер и отлаживать. Потом реализовать коннект двоих игроков к серверу

Comment: покопайте jetty\tomcat + есть хороший [курс](https://stepic.org/course/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-Java-(%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-1)-146/syllabus) по обучению разработки серверов на java, преподаватель из топового университета по айти и разработчик аллодов и скайфоржа(очень популярные ММОРПГ игры) удачи

Comment: если серверную часть делать на ASP.NET, то я бы использовал SignalR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Добываете сервер.
2. Пишете серверную часть своей игры.
3. Делаете match-making для игроков (подбор пар). Например, все игроки, по нажатию своих кнопок, рапортуют серверу что готовы играть, а он подбирает пары между ними.
4. Когда есть пара, создаете на сервере для нее "комнату", это типа логический мини-серверок для игры, где игроки могут обмениваться данными друг с другом (ходы и т.п.).
5. Выдаете игрокам доступ в комнату.
6. Игроки заходят (если не передумали) и начинают игру.